# Direct product of quotient by the same group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ finite group and proper normal $H$ subgroup of $G$ but not a subgroup of $Z(G)$. Is there a $G,H$ such that:

$$ (G/H) \times H \cong G $$

I've looked at: $(g H,h)\mapsto (gh)$ we get that this map is isomorphism whenever: $(gH,h) \circ (g'H,h') = ((g \circ g')H,h\circ h') \mapsto g\circ g' \circ h \circ h' = g \circ h \circ g' \circ h'$. This certainly works whenever elements of $G$ commute with $H$. Question arises if maybe there could be a more cunning way to construct isomorphism that would work, as in general for $H \not \leq Z(G)$ this doesn't work.

Comment: Please don't just state questions! Your question already has already two votes to close and one down vote. It will likely get closed soon, as it is missing context and effort. (If you want a long read, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960). Else, just edit the question to say where you found the question and what you've tried.)

Comment: @user1729 I've added some context. I just don't feel like I've made any meaningful progress there. Question is precisely where my previous reasoning failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $G_1$ and $G_2$ two groups, with $G_2$ not abelian (that is, $Z(G_2) \ne G_2$).

Let $G= G_1 \times G_2$ and $H=1 \times G_2$.

Then, $H$ is a proper normal subgroup of $G$, $H \not \leq Z(G)$, $G/H \cong G_1$, and $(G/H) \times H \cong G$.